# What are Crime Sweeps?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I saw a destination in my HUD called "Crime Sweep", I didn't stop there to check what was going on, what can it be? Is it like a combat zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crime sweep is similar to a combat zone, but it is used for PowerPlay. A few powers use these as part of their expansion goals.

For example, Arissa's Expansion goal is to enter a crime sweep and fight against corrupted enforcement.

Kills inside a crime sweep will reward you with 1 PP and some merits to be turned in (if you are aligned to the power the crime sweep involves)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a combat zone that pays in Powerplay merits instead of credits.

If you are pledged to Arissa Lavigny-Duval, you can enter the Crime Sweep, have the correct faction automatically picked for you, and destroy the hostile (red) ships.

If you are pledged to any other power, you can enter the Crime Sweep, use the right-hand panel to select the *other* faction, and destroy red ships.

You can check the "Powers Contact" in a station in that system to verify exactly what to do in that system to either support or undermine the power that has the Crime Sweeps.

Crime Sweeps are Arissa Lavigny-Duval's specific type. Some of the other powers have their own types of special combat zone, like a "Military Strike" zone, etc...

If you're pledged to the power with the special combat zone, each hostile ship you destroy in the special combat zone will give you one powerplay merit for that system (whether preparation, expansion or fortification). If you're pledged to a different power, each ship will give you one powerplay merit for *undermining* that system. In either case, you will need to travel to a Control system for the power you are pledged with to turn it in and get credit for it.

Comment: I don't think that undermining is possible the way you describe it. I'm pledged to Aisling Duval and entered a Military Strike Zone in one of Denton Patreus' expansion systems. I selected the "System Resistance" faction then destroyed one of Patreus' ships, but received no Powerplay point that I could turn in later on (I already have some PP from destroying . I also checked the system in Patreus' Power Play overview screen, but the opposition number remained unchanged.

Comment: Addition to previous comment: Undermining _may_ work like that, but it depends on the combination of 1) which power you are pledged to, and 2) which power you want to undermine. For Aisling Duval supporters like me, only undermining Zachary Hudson's expansion attempts works by fighting in a Military Strike zone, but undermining Denton Patreus works differently. To find out how it works for _you_: Open the overview page of the power you want to undermine. Select the "Expansion" or "Control" tab and read the instructions how to undermine the respective activity of the opposing power.